# Write XSLT Grouping

Tags: xslt

I have a simple XML with two levels (Header and Line) of tags such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Header>
    <line>Line 1</line>
    <line>Line 2</line>
    <line>Line 3</line>
    <line>Line 4</line>
    <line>Line 5</line>
    <line>Line 6</line>
    <line>Line 7</line>
    <line>Line 8</line>
    <line>Line 9</line>
</Header>
```

I need to group the lines on sets of X (X=3 for example) lines so that my output is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Header>
    <set>
        <line>Line 1</line>
        <line>Line 2</line>
        <line>Line 3</line>
    </set>
    <set>
        <line>Line 4</line>
        <line>Line 5</line>
        <line>Line 6</line>
    </set>
    <set>
        <line>Line 7</line>
        <line>Line 8</line>
        <line>Line 9</line>
    </set>
</Header>
```

How do I write a XSLT that can do this kind of transformation?

Comment: @otavio You are probably using a buggy, non-compliant XSLT processor, or, more likely, changed the source XML document, or changed the code. – Dimitre Novatchev (0 secs ago)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The following transformation produces the required result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vN" select="3"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
           select="line[position() mod $vN = 1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="line">
    <set>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select= 
       ". 
       | 
        following-sibling::line[position() &lt; $vN]"/>
    </set>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="line" mode="copy">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Header>
    <line>Line 1</line>
    <line>Line 2</line>
    <line>Line 3</line>
    <line>Line 4</line>
    <line>Line 5</line>
    <line>Line 6</line>
    <line>Line 7</line>
    <line>Line 8</line>
    <line>Line 9</line>
</Header>
```

**the result is**:

```
<Header>
  <set>
    <line>Line 1</line>
    <line>Line 2</line>
    <line>Line 3</line>
  </set>
  <set>
    <line>Line 4</line>
    <line>Line 5</line>
    <line>Line 6</line>
  </set>
  <set>
    <line>Line 7</line>
    <line>Line 8</line>
    <line>Line 9</line>
  </set>
</Header>
```

**Do note the following**:

1. **The use of the XPath `mod` operator** to find out the first `line` element in every group of `vN` elements.
2. **The use of modes**, in order to be able to process different `line` elements by different templates

Comment: it worked after I changed 

<xsl:apply-templates 
           select="line[position() mod $vN = 1]"/>

to

<xsl:apply-templates 
           select="//line[position() mod $vN = 1]"/>

Comment: You're right Dimitre! I've just found my mistake and implemented the same concept in my real problem and it seems to work fine.
Thanks again! (I'll remove the previous comment)

Answer (score 1):

In general in XSLT if you want to create a heirarchy from a list you can make use of the preceding-sibling and following-sibling keywords.  This is easist if there is a marker entry between sets.

As you don't have a marker as such in this case I imagine a solution could involve the following-sibling keyword and the mod operator.  The mod providing the division between sets.

I haven't tried it but that would be my first start.

[xslt](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) is normally a good place to start with understanding the different keywords.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html shows a slightly less ugly way of doing this using XSLT 2.0. The key element is this one:

`<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-ending-with="*[position() mod 3 = 0]">`

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible. Has the desired output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/Header">
    <Header>
      <xsl:for-each select="line">
        <xsl:if test="not(number()=0) and position() mod 3 = 0">
          <set>
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
            <line><xsl:value-of select="../line[position()=($pos -2)]"/></line>
            <line><xsl:value-of select="../line[position()=($pos -1)]"/></line>
            <line><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></line>
            </set>
        </xsl:if>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </Header>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(The $pos-1, $pos-2 thing is not very pretty)